# Django filter with weird regex

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models

Going through some legacy code, I've stumbled upon this regex in a model filter:

```
"[[:<:]](%s)[[:>:]]" % value
```

I get that the inner square braces are matching literal square braces, but I couldn't find any reference to the colons and lt/gt.

What should this be matching?

Comment: What is the context of this snippet of code? Just `"[[:<:]](%s)[[:>:]]" % value` doesn't say anything more than that `value` is to be added inside the `[[:<:]][[:>:]] part. How is it called, and with what etc.?

Comment: @timss Wow, 4 upvotes, ok. It's a regex from a model filter, just like it says in the first sentence. And the question was about the regex itself. What is the regex going to match, as is? The interpolated value can be considered as string of not-regex-special characters, and therefore should be disregarded. Not sure there's any more context to be given.

Comment: What is a "model filter" supposed to be ??? Or do you mean a _template_ filter ? But anyway: I'd like to see the line where this "regexp" is actually used, as it's a really really weird pattern - so weird I suspect it's either a mistake or not supposed to be used with Python's bultin regexp module.

Comment: Oh man, I'd really like to see the context of this. I'd love to figure out what the hell they were trying to do.

Comment: @TomDickin If I recall correctly (and I tried real hard to forget that particular project) the interpolated regex was used as a __regex field lookup. There was no chance of field containing anything that would match. Ever. So, my guess was that the author wanted to neutralize the query and send anyone reading his code on a wild-goose chase in one blow.

Comment: @cbaby, Ha, thanks for the reply. It's times like this it would be good if git/svn blame also provided current address details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters on your question point out, this is probably a mistake, or someone yanking your chain. I can't imagine how it could be useful. But to answer your question explicitly, here are some of things it would match. This assumes Python has already replaced `%s` with `foo`

```
[]foo:]
:]foo:]
<]foo:]
<]foo>]
[]foo>]
[]foo:]
[]foo[]
```

Maybe this was a (failed) attempt to find something like `<foo>` or `:foo:`

Explanation of the regex (I've removed the repetitive `:` which are superfluous, and seem to indicate that this is all a mistake, or not meant to be run using Python's `re`):

```
[[:<] # match one `[` or `:` or `<`
]     # one literal right bracket
(     # open capture group
foo   # literal string `foo`, or whatever replaced `%s`
)     # close capture group
[[>:] # match one `[` or `>` or `:` 
]     # one literal right bracket
```

What does it all mean? Your guess is as good as anyone's.